Network scheme based on traceroute commands - is my thinking correct?
I want to create a hypothetical scheme of network containing the 3 routers (R1, R2 and R3) that were listed when running 2 separate traceroute commands.

traceroute 1:
1  ***
   (...)
9  R1 (80.249.209.102)
10 R2 (156.17.252.37)
   (...)
30 ***


traceroute 2:
1  ***
   (...)
8  R3 (156.17.254.105)
9  R2 (156.17.252.37)
   (...)
30 ***


I came up with such a hypothetical scheme:
          | 
+---------------------+        +---------------------+
|  eth0:              |        |  eth0:              |
|  <IP1/mask1>        |        |  <IP3/mask3>        |
|                     |        |                     |
|    Router R1        |        |  Router R3          |
|                     |        |                     |
|  eth1:              |        |  eth1:              |
|  156.17.252.38/28   |        | 156.17.252.39/28    |
+---------------------+        +---------------------+
          |                              |
          |                              |
          |         +------------+       |
          +---------|   Switch   |-------+
                    +------------+
                          |
                          |
                +--------------------+
                |  eth0:             |
                |  156.17.252.37/28  |
                |                    |
                |   Router R2        |
                |                    |
                |  eth1:             |
                |  <IP2/mask2>       |
                +--------------------+

Now, is that a valid combination of networks / connection of routers?
I put the switch between the interfaces of my routers since from the traceroute results I know that R1 must be directly connected to the interface with IP 156.17.252.37 and R3 must be directly connected to the interface with IP 156.17.252.37/28. As I understand it - the only way to connect 2 different interfaces of 2 different routers (R1 and R3) to the same interface of the same router (R2) is to use switch. Is that correct?
